# Can "ab" be used with a pronoun?

Tags: preposition

As I've experienced the preposition "ab" has local, temporal usages. But I was wondering if it has usage with a personal pronoun such as "dir" or "mir".

> After you nothing has changed in my life. (Ab dir nichts ist in meinem Leben geändert.)

Here is a time period implied, that's why it seems to me possible after all. I don't know but that would be completely wrong. Actually this usage is very common in my mother language, especially in poetry.Maybe with more explaination I would be imply "after you left me or after our farewell".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ein Beispiel klingt für mich falsch. Ich würde "seit" statt "ab" verwenden.

> Seit dir hat sich nichts in meinem Leben geändert.

Man verwendet "seit" für Zeitpunkte in der Vergangenheit ("seit letztem Montag") und "ab" für Zeitpunkte in der Zukunft ("ab nächstem Montag"). "seit" bezieht sich auf einen Zeitpunkt oder ein Ereignis ("seit dem Erdbeben").

Ich würde auch mit "seit" kein Pronomen verwenden, sondern z.B. sagen

> Seit ich dich kenne, ...
>
> Von diesem denkwürdigen Tag an...

Mit Pronomen geht es auch

> Seit dir weiss ich, ...

wobei dann impliziert ist, dass "seit dir" z.B. "seit ich dich kenne" oder "seit wir verheiratet sind" bedeutet.

Answer (score 3):

There actually is a way to use *nach dir* like that - 
I am not sure if it is what you're looking for (you did not supply enough context in your example to judge that) but it would mean "nachdem wir unsere Beziehung beendet haben..." - i.e after we broke up. Thus meaning the exact opposite of what Robert is referring to. You would use that in sentences like

*Nach dir habe ich keine Frau mehr geküsst*

*Ab* or *seit* (that maybe even works somewhat) does not sound quite right to me in that context.

EDIT: Now that you have supplied a bit more context: This (*nach dir*) actually seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: here is a temporal usage you mention with "nach dir", right?

Comment: right - like in "nach Weihnachten" ;)